# Como convertir un file .exe a .asm en Assembly

Tags: assembly

estoy aprendiendo Assembly, utilizo el programa de DOSBox-X, tengo que convertir un file .exe a .asm y no entiendo bien como hacerlo todavía, aprecio todo tipo de ayuda, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Debes descargar un desensamblardor. Las instrucciones binarias también puedes verlas usando un editor ansi(recomiendo HxD).
El editor te pondrán las instrucciones en hexadecimal separadas y sera difícil entender cada cosas a la primera, después te acostumbra. Aquí tengo algo que hice, no he tenido mucho tiempo de seguirlo:

```
Hexadecimal binario,   instrucción i386 -Mintel
        b8 2a      ,   "mov eax,""0x2a"
        ba ff      ,   "mov edx,""0xff"
        b8 16      ,   "mov eax,""0x16"
         50        ,   "push eax"
         52        ,   "push edx"
        ba ff      ,   "not","eax,"
       83 c0 01    ,   "add", "eax,""0x1"
    e8 fc ff ff ff ,    call   18 <_main_+0x18>
         58        ,   "pop eax"
        31 c0      ,   "xor eax," "eax"
          c3       ,        "ret"
          CC       ,        "int3"
```

Para desesambarlo use:

```
objdump -a -d -Mintel main.o
```

> Como notaras puse el archivo main objeto, si lo haces con un ya compilado sera mucho código basura que no sera el tuyo.

[objdump](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) no se si vino con [nasm](https://www.nasm.org/) o con gcc pero es calidad usarlo, lo recomiendo.

> > Edit: Interprete mal la pregunta y por eso edite la respuesta...

Comment: `objdump` viene con [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/). Tal vez mingw o msys lo traiga para Windows. Existen otros desensambladores como IDA, https://binary.ninja/, ghidra o godbolt.